# How to restart the setInterval in jquery so that when the user Click the counter restarts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to restart the setInterval in jquery so that when the user Click the counter restarts?

So i created a tabs section so that it will cycle to the next tab after 12 sec. However, I would like to restart time if the user clicks on a desired tab so that the user gets a new set of 12 sec.

I'm a novice in jquery so please explain thoroughly. Many Thanks.

```
$("li.tab").click(function () {


    $("li.tab").removeClass("select");
       $(".featured_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(1600); //Fade in the active ID content
    $(this).addClass("select");





});

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {

    var lastChild = $('li.select').is(':last-child');

    if (lastChild) {

        $('li.tab').removeClass('select ')
        $("li.tab:first").addClass('select ');
        return false;

    } else {
        $("li.select").removeClass('select').next().addClass('select');
        return false;
    }

}, 12000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval):

```
$("li.tab").click(function () {
    // ...
    refreshIntervalId = clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    // setInterval again to re-start the 'timer'
    // ...
});
```

Comment: +1 for your +1 - We have to provide some context for beginners :p

Comment: @John - Looks like we both might owe one to this [@Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) for gracefully pointing out confusing of `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval`!

Comment: Fun fact: Chrome, at least, will clear a timeout with "clearInterval()" and clear an interval with "clearTimeout" (at least that was so last time I checked)

Comment: it cleared the interval but it did not restart this is what my code:

$("li.tab").click(function () {
    // ...
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
  setInterval(function () {

        var lastChild = $('li.select').is(':last-child');

        if (lastChild) {

            $('li.tab').removeClass('select ')
            $("li.tab:first").addClass('select ');
            return false;

        } else {
            $("li.select").removeClass('select').next().addClass('select');
            return false;
        }

    }, 12000);
});

Comment: My guess is you forgot to store the new `refreshIntervalId` - see my correction

Comment: i still get the same result the setInterval does not restart. Please see code

Answer (score 2):

```
//Stop
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);

//Start again
setInterval(function () {
  ...
}, 12000)
```